# How to Stop python Programm if a certain URL is reachable

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-requests, urllib

Can anybody help me with this small dilemma? I want to stop the python programm if the IP address 10.10.10.2 is reachable WITHIN 10 SECONDS. if it is not reachable in 10 SECONDS it should handle the exception and continue with the programm. if 10.10.10.2 is reachable then it should print "This IP address is reachable you are using the wrong device please disconnect" i thought about putting a ´´´sys.exit(1)´´´ after the except but im constantly getting errors. I am very new to python or any programming language for that matter so any example snippet codes and help are much appreciated

```
import pandas as pd
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib.request
import time
from urllib.error import HTTPError


print(100*"#")

try:
    preflash = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.10.10.2", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", preflash)
    print("IP address: 10.10.10.2 is reachable")
except urllib.error.URLError:
    correct = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.100.5", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", correct)
    print("IP address: 192.168.100.5 is reachable")

 
print(100*"#")    
# Declare url String    
url_str = 'http://192.168.100.2/globals.xml'

# open webpage and read values
xml_str = urllib.request.urlopen(url_str).read()

# Parses XML doc to String for Terminal output
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml_str)

# Finding the neccassary Set points/ Sollwerte from the xmldoc

time.sleep(0.5)
# prints the order_number from the xmldoc
order_number = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('order_number')
print("The Order number of the current device is:", order_number[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
print(100*"-")
```

The output of the python programm looks like this:

```
Web page status code: 200
IP address: 10.10.10.2 is reachable the programm will shut down in 5 seconds
####################################################################################################
The Order number of the current device is: 58184
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The programm needs to shut down if 10.10.10.2 is reachable

Comment: please post what error you are getting.

Comment: @MZ please take another look at it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Quite Stupid of me, all i needed to do was to add sys.exit(1) function before the except.

```
try:
    preflash = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.10.10.2", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", preflash)
    print("IP address: 10.10.10.2 is reachable")
    sys.exit(1)
except urllib.error.URLError:
    correct = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.100.5", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", correct)
    print("IP address: 192.168.100.5 is reachable")
```